# UDK - problem packaging/publishing the game

Tags: udk, unreal, distribution

I have set up all the config files to my game classes and am able to launch the game to test everything.

Although when I package the game, it still runs the UT deathmatch game?

What other lines in the config files should be changed to make it default to my game and default map once published/packaged?

Comment: It might help to show which configuration files you have already edited, and to what values.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented here on the UDN:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DevelopmentKitProgramming.html#Configuring,%20Compiling%20and%20Testing

> You can also change the default game type to use when none is
>   specified in UDKGame.ini in the [Engine.GameInfo] section. Change
>   DefaultGame and DefaultServerGame to =MyMod.SuperFunGame. Make sure
>   your gametype implements SetGameType() so it can prevent the gametype
>   from being overridden.

I should mention there's a bit more info here:

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DevelopmentKitDeployment.html

> To propagate this change or any other ini change into your packaged
>   mod, you'll need to also modify the defaults in DefaultGame.ini.